# simple_html_dom not returning <h1> elements?

Tags: php, parsing, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I'm testing a parser using SIMPLE_HTML_DOM and while parsing
the returned HTML DOM from this URL: [HERE](http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4360333,00.html)

It is not finding the H1 elements...
I tried returning all the div's with success.

I'm using a simple request for diagnosing this problem:

```
foreach($html->find('H1') as $value) { echo "<br />F: ".htmlspecialchars($value); }
```

While looking at the source code I realized that:

- h1 is upper case -> H1 - but the SIMPLE_HTML... is handling that:

  ```
              //PaperG - If lowercase is set, do a case insensitive test of the value of the selector.
          if ($lowercase) {
              $check = $this->match($exp, strtolower($val), strtolower($nodeKeyValue));
          } else {
              $check = $this->match($exp, $val, $nodeKeyValue);
          }
          if (is_object($debugObject)) {$debugObject->debugLog(2, "after match: " . ($check ? "true" : "false"));}
  ```

Can any body help me understanding what is going on here?

Comment: Note the difference: `H1 != h1`. and you can print all the results from `$html` out in case there is something missing.

Comment: What does your browser DOM say? The page you linked to has invalid HTML so it's possible PHP's parser is choking on the errors.

Comment: H1 is not h1 i know, but simple html dom parser is handling that by lowering the case of the input tag and the matching one... (tested). the dom showing on the browser is finding the h1 tag (there is only one on the page) that includes the article title - search for class=text20b on the page source u will find it. i echo $html and h1 is there!? this is very confusing...

Comment: In the URl , they are using **H1** . That is beyond the standard AFAIK and may be causing problem.

Comment: Try downloading the page and change **H1** to **h1** and then parse , it should work. Your code looks like okay :)

Comment: HTML tag names are always lower cased. that's true in simple, phpquery, DOM and every other parser as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it...

But cant explain it!

I tested with another code including H1 (uppercase) and it worked.

While playing with the SIMPLE_HTML_DOM code i commented the "remove_noise" and now its working 
perfectly, I think it's because that this website has invalid HTML and
the noise remover is removing too much and not ending after the end tags scripts:

```
    // $this->remove_noise("'<\s*script[^>]*[^/]>(.*?)<\s*/\s*script\s*>'is");
    // $this->remove_noise("'<\s*script\s*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*script\s*>'is");
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
        $oHtml = str_get_html($html);
        foreach($oHtml->find('h1') as $element)
        {
            echo $element->innertext;
        }
```

You will also use regular expression following function return an array of all h1 tag's innertext

```
  function getH1($yourhtml)
{
    $h1tags = preg_match_all("/(<h1.*>)(\w.*)(<\/h1>)/isxmU", $yourhtml, $patterns);
    $res    = array();
    array_push($res, $patterns[2]);
    array_push($res, count($patterns[2]));
    return $res;
}
```